# Excel Export Treating Date Time as Number

Tags: angular, typescript, formatting, export-to-excel

I am having an issue in specific date while exporting excel file. Please check the excel file screenshot for better understanding

[image]

In case of Date '01/02/2019 00:00:00', it is treating it as number. All other dates are displaying fine. 
Below is the code

```
fireEvent() {
        const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(this.table.nativeElement);
        const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
        XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'ExportDatiTable.xlsx');
    }
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Please can anyone update about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(this.table.nativeElement, 
         {dateNF:'mm/dd/yyyy;@',cellDates:true, raw: true});
        const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
        XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'ExportDatiTable.xlsx');
```